# Overwrite handwriting on Android (input to word processor, math-aware)

Tags: text-processing, word-processor, text, app, android-app

[image: Let, written as a word, then as L, then Le, then Let, in overwrite handwriting]I am trying to save some trees.

In order to do this, I would like to develop a system for true handwriting that can be used on Android.

In order to do this, this would have to be an overwrite handwriting.

I plan to develop the system to write mathematics as well (such as integral signs with functions inside).

In order to do this, the overwrite handwriting needs to be such because:

- writing space on Android screens, by dragging the finger, is limited
- the finger needs to swipe across the screen, in the same approximate area, one swipe after the other
- it is easier to write, without lifting the finger

Given these premises, please see the handwriting picture attached.

I have drawn the word "Let", (often used when starting mathematics proofs).

The colors are just for the reader to view the different letters separately.

A separate app from Gboard with which to write would do for the time being.

Has anyone developed such an "overwrite handwriting" app (for calligraphic and math text input, which could go on a word processor capable of writing mathematics).

Psychologically, proof writing, should improve, of you are able to write continuously (I was able to experience this in college).

Thank you for your support.

See the attached picture.

Where can I find such an app?

Has anyone done this?

Is anyone willing to develop such an app?

Thanks.

NOTE: The handwriting would only be input overwritten, but would come out, onto the word precessor, normal (not overwritten).